# Repository Query Loading Related Data

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

The microsoft docs demonstrate using an example like so:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
        .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
            .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
                .ThenInclude(author => author.Photo)
        .ToList();
```

Is there a way to do this using the:

`Abp.Application.Services.IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>`?

I can already see the `IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding` method but I need to fetch deeper than just the next level down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the article on [Developing a Multi-Tenant SaaS Application with ASP.NET Core](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Developing-MultiTenant-SaaS-ASP.NET-CORE-Angular/index.html#applicationservices):

```cs
public async Task<EventDetailOutput> GetDetailAsync(EntityDto<Guid> input)
{
    var @event = await _eventRepository
        .GetAll()
        .Include(e => e.Registrations)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.User)
        .Where(e => e.Id == input.Id)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    // ...
}
```

Abstracting `ThenInclude` behind `IRepository` was explored, but found to be impractical:

- https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2167
- https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2171

Comment: it might be just me but i was slightly confused at first by the actual name of the 'GetAll()' method.  i wrongly assumed it returned actual entities at that point.  Just an idea - but i personally would find the name 'GetAllQuery' more obvious.  please don't take this as heavy criticism - just the way i look at things :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this :

```cs
public async Task<EventDetailOutput> GetDetailAsync(EntityDto<Guid> input)
{
    var @event = await _eventRepository
        .GetAllIncluding(e => e.Registrations, e => e.Registrations.User)
        .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == input.Id);

    // ...
}
```

The only limitation is you can't include the second level after including a collection, due to a bug in Intellisense : [Include->ThenInclude for a collection](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6560).

Comment: "I can already see the IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding method but I need to fetch deeper than just the next level down." My example is fetching more than a level down ("e => e.Registrations.User"), why isn't it good for you ? It's basically the same as using "Include" and "ThenInclude" but combining this using "GetAllIncluding...

Comment: because it did not add anything new to that which i had already stated in my original question.  don't sweat it all good :-)

Comment: Ok. the last sentence of your question made me understand that you knew "GetAllIncluding" existed, but you were thinking it could only fetch one level down.